Can't connect to MongoDB cluster via sinatra app but works with mongosh
We are migrating from GCP to our bare metal Kubernetes cluster.
I need to "lift and shift" some VMs from GCP to k8s.
One of the VMs is running a docker image that connects to a MongoDB cluster hosted on Atlas.
I added the cluster's IP range to the Network Access on MongoDB Atlas and I can use mongosh to connect, I can connect also within the running container.
The problem is that the app run in the container (rails app that uses the gem mongoid v7.0.5) fails to connect with the following error:
No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x44772020 tag_sets=[] max_staleness=nil> using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015 (Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable)

I noticed that we have set up a Network Peering with GCP. I have been wondering if the Network Peering has anything to do with the error; in that case it would be surprising that I can still connect via mongosh, though.
Any idea about what I can try to solve this?

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If not I will be happy to assist you.What should I do when someone answers my question?

Regarding the error mesage please be noted that if the machine has IPv6 enabled, then Rails/mongoid tries to connect to mongodb via IPv6, and this fails. Try changing your hosts settings to localhost:27017 in your mongoid.yaml file. By default,Mongo runs on port 27017.
Please follow the below steps to overcome this error.

Change config/mongoid.yml to run at localhost:27017

Create the empty directories C:data/db

Then run mongoD and check whether it works.


Also please refer to this document to learn more about setting up Mongoid configuration files.
Note: Network peering typically involves a private connection between two networks,usually between GCP and MongoDB atlas. And if your container is running in a private network within your bare-metal cluster but you are accessing Atlas via public IP, the container might be configured to connect to a different address than mongosh.
